# fill 2 inputs with jquery autocomplete using mysql and php in a loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, loops, jquery-autocomplete

Ok, so I'm kinda new to this.. I've googled the crud out of this and I'm just not understanding.

I have 2 inputs, description and barcode

I need to search in the description field, and autocomplete the description and barcode upon description suggestion selection.

Here is what I have so far, I cant seem to figure out how to add the php array to the Jquery
(granted no array is shown, this is my working code for a single input field)
 Someone please dumb this down for me.

```
    <?php //My Inputs (are in a loop) *** ?>

    <input name="<?php echo 'ingdes'.$y ?>" type="text"  value="<?php  issetValue($ingdes[$y]) ?>"class="autosearch" id="<?php echo 'ingdes'.$y ?>" size="45" autocomplete='off'  /> <!-- THIS IS THE DESCRIPTION -->

     DESC

     <input name="<?php echo 'ingcode'.$y ?>" type="text" value="<?php issetValue($ingcode[$y]) ?>" class="code" id="<?php echo 'ingcode'.$y ?>" size="12"  /> 
     BARCD   <!-- THIS IS THE BARCODE -->

    <?php // End My inputs ***

          // My function ***

          public function jsAutoSearch() { ?>

          <script>
          $(function() {
          var availableTags = [ <?php

          $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $this->usernameid ORDER BY name");

          while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false){
          echo '"'.$row['name'].'",';}?> 
          /* $row['barcode1'] is the additional field I need to get working and send to the other input field  */  

          ""];
          $( ".autosearch" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags
          });
          });
          </script>

          <?php }

          // End my function
```

My attempt at the array ****************

```
    public function jsAutoSearch() { 

       $return_arr = array();
    $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $this->usernameid ORDER BY name");

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false){
    $row_array['name']  = $row['name']; // THIS IS THE DESCRIPTION
    $row_array['barcode'] = $row['barcode1']; // THIS IS THE BARCODE
          array_push( $return_arr, $row_array );
    } ?>
    <script>

    $( ".autosearch" ).autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo json_encode($return_arr),'\n'?>",
    select: function (event, ui) {
    var item = ui.item;
    if(item) {
    $(".autosearch").val(item.name); <!-- THIS IS THE DESCRIPTION -->
    $(".ingcode1").val(item.barcode); <!-- THIS IS THE BARCODE -->
    }
    ;}
    })

</script>


<?php }
```

Comment: dumb which part down? can you make array in php? Data structure for autocomplete is wrong...   need to read docs about data for that. Page is a disorganized mess...need help theer?  Hard to know where to start. Suggest you focus on one issue at a time and start with ones that are most troubling

Comment: The inputs are in a loop, the full markup is obviously not present. As for the function, I know very little about java script/jquery. I can easily put what I need into an array using php, but I don't even know where to start with integrating the two languages. I echoed my php into the jquery function to simplify things in an effort to just get it working. And it does, but only with one input. My attempts at two inputs were even more embarrassing to post. I also don't understand the documentation well enough to figure out how to split my array to the required input fields.

Comment: Really all I need is to know, is how to search from a dynamically labeled input. Also have it fill itself and one additional field with data from two Mysql columns.

Comment: As an example: When someone searches the description it will list all item description names, and then upon selection of the autocomplete data for description names, is will fill the description name and the adjacent barcode field with a barcode.

Comment: I'm also the type that has to reverse engineer code in an effort to learn, so ANY working model closely resembling what I'm trying to do would be helpful. But I do greatly appreciate the help given so far!

Comment: majority of what you need in jQuery is in the demos..`view source`   do you want array sent to page on load, or dynamically do search from server as user types? Read data structure part of docs also regarding `label/value object` or `strings` in array.

Comment: Dynamic search as the user types, the data in the db is just a bunch of strings. It's just getting the correct columns to the correct inputs after the user chooses the result from description.

Comment: Then you are jumping way ahead of the game showing code to try to select all from DB and get it into page. DB search using AJAX would be filtered based on term. STart undertsanding how remote autocomplete works first. Numerous examples in docs... and lots of tutorials on web. Halsf of your code above is now not needed in main page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <?//*****************search.php*********************

     $searchterm = $_GET['term'];
   $return_arr = array();
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $object1->usernameid WHERE name LIKE    '%$searchterm%' ORDER BY name");

 while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false){
       $names[] = array( name => $row['name'], barcode => $row['defcode'] ) ; 
    } 


 // Cleaning up the term
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));
// Rudimentary search
$matches = array();
foreach($names as $name){
if(stripos($name['name'], $term) !== false){
    // Add the necessary "value" and "label" fields and append to result set
    $name['value'] = $name['name'];
    $name['label'] = "{$name['name']}, {$name['defcode']}";
    $matches[] = $name;
}
  }
 // Truncate, encode and return the results
 $matches = array_slice($matches, 0, 5);
 print json_encode($matches);?>

//********************** JQuery *****************************************

       <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
var ac_config = {
    source: "search.php",
    select: function(event, ui){
        $("#ingdes<?php echo $y ?>").val(ui.item.name);
        $("#ingcode<?php echo $y ?>").val(ui.item.barcode);

    },
    minLength:1
};
$("#ingdes<?php echo $y ?>").autocomplete(ac_config);
   });
 </script>
```